# Every print starts with an exclamation point using react-native-bluetooth-escpos-printer

Tags: react-native, android-bluetooth, thermal-printer, escpos

Every print starts with an exclamation point with react-native-bluetooth-escpos-printer
using
@brooons/react-native-bluetooth-escpos-printer": "^1.2.0"

here is an example of the print :

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kW0Xk.jpg)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Perhaps the control code is incomplete, such as missing the first code when trying to execute one of these ESC/POS commands. [ESC !](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=23), [FS !](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=174), [GS !](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=34)

Comment: Thank you very much @kunif , i just solved the problem. It was in PrinterCommand file of the library in POS_Print_Text function it has an extra concatenation of GS_! for the beginning of each Text line so i removed that and now it works fine.

Comment: For example, please try to answer yourself with information about what kind of coding you did that caused the problem and how you changed it to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.
It was in PrinterCommand file of the library in POS_Print_Text function it has an extra concatenation of GS_! for the beginning of each Text line so i removed that and now it works fine.